# Nutch readlinkdb does not output anything

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I used Nutch 1.5 to crawl (used the crawl command), post this the readlinkdb dump contains nothing. Also, in an Indexing filter the inlinks is null. What causes the inlinks to be null?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you’re indexing just a particular site. In that case, if `db.ignore.internal.links` in `nutch-default.xml` is true, nutch won’t store internal links. Set it to false in `nutch-site.xml` and your linkdb will start growing.

```
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.internal.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, when adding new links to a page, links from
  the same host are ignored.  This is an effective way to limit the
  size of the link database, keeping only the highest quality
  links.
  </description>
</property>
```